# Win7: How do I find out what process is drawing this object?

Tags: windows-7

One of my workstations has been crap-ified by a coworker. Thankfully he's no longer with us, but the junk he installed still remains. When I log on locally into my account on this workstation, a yellow rectangle pops up on the bottom right of the primary monitor that I can't close. Because it's completely blank, I have no idea what's drawing it, and the process list is kinda long. I'm getting tired of seeing it every time I go to that computer and it's always in front of any window, so it's totally dead space on the screen. Here's a picture of the primary monitor and part of the secondary:

[image]

Although the wise thing to do would be to flatten and reinstall, I can't. For *reasons*. How can I determine what is drawing this so I can get rid of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does anything happen when you Right-Click it, and if you press Windows-Tab to change the focused window, does it show as a window or stay above the aero switch display?

Comment: Nothing that gives it away when I right click or alt-tab, but when alt-tabbing, an icon appears in the mini-window that hints that it's something to do with wireless. That narrows it down a lot actually.

Comment: BAM! Killed it. Thanks a lot. Is there anything I can do when I don't get lucky like that?

Comment: As Scott Rhee suggested, Process Explorer will do the trick. I remember that I used to know of a command that would kill every process but system-necessary ones and ones in use, and then identify the ones that got killed, but i forget exactly what it was...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will help you. Run the tool and drag the target mark (located at the end of its toolbar) to that yellow rectangle you want to investigate. Possibly it will locate a process which is displaying that rectangle. At that stage, you may check its properties (name, path, ...) and/or kill it by right-clicking on the process.